# Can we read the geoip2 database file with .mmdb format like normal file in Python?

Tags: python, maxmind, geoip2

I need to read the whole geoip2 database and insert that data into SQL lite database. I tried to read the .mmdb file in the normal way but it prints random characters.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to download CSV file and import it into SQL lite.

Comment: Yes, It's possible but our project is using mmdb file and it's used for another feature, If I changed it to CSV, I need to fully modify the whole feature.  So and it will be overhead if I keep both mmdb file and CSV file.